# Fetching Data from MySQL using PHP & jQuery and displaying in HTML table matching the user ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have written a simple code to test the fetching of data from MySQL table using PHP and jQuery, but when I search the ID from the search box (I have ID 1 to 4 with user details such as nationalId, firstName, lastName) and it displays 1 when I search 1 to 4 ID which is present in the MySQL table but when i search ID 5 and above (not present in the MySQL table) it outputs "No ID found" which is the correct output as per the ID.

//index.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getUser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Citizenship ID No.<input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Type Your CID" />
          <button type="submit" id="id-submit" value="Track">TRACK</button> 

          <div id ="display"></div>          
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

//connection.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'user');
?>

//getUser.js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#id-submit').on('click', function(){

        var id = $('input#id').val();
            if ($.trim(id) != '') {
                $.post("php/getData.php", { id: id}, function(data) {
                    $('div#display').text(data);

            });

        }

    });
});
```

//getData.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']) === true && empty($_POST['id']) === false){
    require '../sql/connection.php';


    $query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE ID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['id'])) . "'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    echo (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0) ? mysqli_data_seek($result, 0) : 'No ID found';

    }
    ?>
```

//MyMySQL table = userinfo

id nationalID firstName lastName

1  1200345    Sam       Hunt

2  1200346    John      Denver

3  1200347    Peter     Parker

4  1200348    Josh      Matthew

Comment: id 5 is no logner in your MySQL table = userinfo so how to fetch the sql id number 5

Comment: @Sabastian Sonam Ugyen, what is the problem, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Devina Leong I want to output the users information using HTML form.

Comment: @Mohammad Malek I understand your concern but I have mentioned that it outputs "ID not found" which is the correct output. I am emphasizing on the ID 1 to 4 which should output the user information when I type id 1 to 4

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the programe but i think it will be right output for what are you asking. As i understood that you want the output data in the form of table when you click the button. To acheive this you can directly fetch and print the data in table in php itself.

THIS IS THE CODE WHICH YOU REQUIRE

```
  <?php
 if (isset($_POST['id']) === true && empty($_POST['id']) === false){
require '../sql/connection.php';


$query = "SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE ID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($con,        trim($_POST['id'])) . "'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 echo '<table>';
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<th>';
 echo 'id'; 
 echo '</th>';
echo '<th>';
echo 'nationalID'; 
echo '</th>'; 
echo '<th>';
echo 'firstName'; 
echo '</th>';
echo '<th>';
echo 'lastName'; 
echo '</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row['id']; 
  echo '</td>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row['nationalID']; 
 echo '</td>'; 
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row['firstName']; 
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td>';
 echo $row['lastName']; 
echo '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
 }
}
$con->close();
?>
```

---

***And try to use the prepared statements to prevent sql injection.***

Comment: Thanks for the code it works but it displays raw HTML tags and not table. and what if the ID is not there, i want to display a message  saying "No ID matched". I tried with "else {echo "No ID matched!";}" but nothing is displayed.